# Importing Classification Sheet from NVIVO - any way?

Tags: tables, appendix

I am writing a systematic literature review andusing Nvivo for data extraction and synthesis. I have made a classification sheet with all information for my Descriptive Analysis table ( Authors - Article title - journal - date - vol- no - abstract - keyword), that I need to attach as an appendix.
Is there any way I can attach this? I only see the option to export the classification sheet as a txt-file. If not, ill just need to make a bunch of tables manually I guess?

Comment: Too many to answer. No idea of Nvivo, but if the program can export to .docx, .htm, and .xls, a priori, all of these  formats can be exported to latex as tables automatically in several ways,  but your mileage may vary with each concrete source file and the selected export  workflow. Tab-delimited text (.txt) can also be used to construct tables automatically in several ways. Moreover, LaTeX can also include Nvivo PDF outputs "as is".

Comment: Thankyou Fran! Could you quickly explain what you mean by Nvivo PDF outputs "as is"?

Comment: Sigle PDF pages can be included as normal images (like PNG or JPG files) with the `page`  option to select one page, or you use package `pdfpages` to insert several pages at once. Run `texdoc pdfpages` to see the manual, or seach it in CTAN, or searh "pdfpages" it in this site to see many examples of use.

Comment: [according to their doc](https://help-nv.qsrinternational.com/20/win/Content/files/export-files.htm#WhatfiletypescanIexportto) the txt are tab delimited values so csv but tab not comma, you could use a latex package like datatool or, more flexibly, just edit the file change tab to `&`  and put `\\ ` at the end of lines and you have a latex table